# Match the start of the file or a newline (Ragel)

Tags: ragel

I'm using ragel with C as the host language.

I can recognise a newline simply with '\n', but I need to recognise the start of the file as an alternative.

In other implementations of regex this could be given by `\A` or `$`, but `$` is reserved for other purposes, `'\A'` maps to something else (alarm?) and `\A` gives a parser error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's an escape sequence for that. However, you can detect it by checking if Ragel's `ts` variable equals 0.

Answer (score 0):

In text format You have 3 choice:

- Old mac to nr 9 `\n\r` (and Commodore, Apple II, Microware OS-9)
- Unices and new Mac OS X `\n` ( and BeOS, AmigaOS, MorphOS, RISC OS, Multics)
- Windows uses `\r\n` (and  DOS, OS/2, Symbian, DEC RT-11)

in Ragel defining end of line

```
endline = ( "\r" | "\n" )+ @{ increase_line_number; };
```

the start of line is begining `(any - endline)`